# MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; Exception From Running ASP.NET Generated Migrations

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I am attempting to run the following command `Update-Database` the following error is returned:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE `AspNetRoles` (
    `Id` nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    `Name` nvarchar(256) NULL,
    `NormalizedName` nvarchar(256) NULL,
    `ConcurrencyStamp` nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_AspNetRoles` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_AspNetRoles` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)' at line 5
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 43
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 468
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 56
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 296
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 107
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_AspNetRoles` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)' at line 5
```

ApplicationDbContext relevant code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore; using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; using System.Reflection.Metadata; using WebApplication3.Models;

namespace WebApplication3.Data {
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoles>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.ConcurrencyStamp).HasColumnType("longtext");
            });
        }

    } }
```

AspNetRoles returns the following error:

```
CS0246
```

The migrations are those generated by ASP.NET itself.

I have done some research, and have not been able to find a solution for my particular problem, here, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're encountering stems from the `nvarchar(max)`.

It seems that your ConcurrencyStamp column is set up as `nvarchar(max)`, which is not supported in MySQL.

You need to adjust the type of your ConcurrencyStamp field to an acceptable MySQL type. In MySQL, the equivalent of SQL Server's `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is `LONGTEXT`.

For ex:

```
public class AspNetRoles
{
    // other properties...

    [Column(TypeName = "longtext")]
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
Editing my answer to include the users new question/issue.

The issue here is that you are trying to modify the AspNetRoles table via the ApplicationDbContext's OnModelCreating method. However, AspNetRoles is not an Entity that you have defined; it is a table created by the default Identity setup in ASP.NET.

Instead of AspNetRoles, you need to use the IdentityRole class that is part of the ASP.NET Identity system.

Here is how your OnModelCreating method should look:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.ConcurrencyStamp).HasColumnType("longtext");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When I attempt to implement the code you provided in my ApplicationDbContext,<AspNetRoles> gives me the following error: CS0246. How might I fight this? Am I missing a 'using' statement? Thanks again.

Comment: Can you comment or edit your question to include the exact error message so I can help further?

Comment: I have modified my question to include the code relevant to my comment regarding the error.

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you are using the table created by the default Identity setup in ASP.NET, this will solve your issue.